# Powerpoint Edits in Outlook Not Saved

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-powerpoint

Scenario
Microsoft Office 2010 with AutoRecovery turned ON.

1. I create a Powerpoint and save it on my local hard drive.
2. I create an Outlook meeting request, attach my PowerPoint file and send the meeting request.
3. I open the meeting request, then open the attached PowerPoint, and proceed to work (change) the PowerPoint for a few hours.
4. I close the meeting request.
5. I close the PowerPoint. I did not click "Save".

There are zero files in the PowerPoint autorecovery directory.

Question (I think you can see this one coming)
As I didn't manually save the PowerPoint attached to the meeting request, did the PowerPoint actually save to disk, and if yes, where?

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint's autorecovery feature is only invoked when PPT detects a situation that's about to cause it to crash.  It's not an autosave feature.

When you closed the file, did PPT ask if you wanted to save?  If it did and you said no, well ... it did what you told it to do.

However if you closed the file and didn't get the opportunity to save, that may be a bug in PowerPoint.